# Minio vs CubeFS: Comparison

Tags: cloud-storage, minio, blob-storage

I was exploring blob storage for custom deployment. Minio and CubeFS are two among them that I felt was really good. Is there any one out there who has experience with both of these tools? If anyone does have any experience could you please shed some light on the performance, stability and other primary aspects of these tools.

Comment: Server Fault is not the place to respond for request for proposals. And you don't specify any requirements anyway, so its impossible to answer. Please define what you want better, try those and maybe other things, then edit your question when you have done your research.  If you just want to list software and tech, there is  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  also on Stack Exchange.